# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

why do I get error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
create view viewAss
as select a.kd_ass,m.nama
from mahasiswa m ,asisten a, honor h
where m.NIM = a.nim and a.kd_ass = h.kd_ass
group by a.kd_ass,m.nama,h.honors
having h.honors > (select avg(h.honors) from honor)
```

> Command(s) completed successfully.

but, when I run ..

```
select * from viewAss
```

Error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
create view viewAss
as 
 select a.kd_ass
       ,m.nama
from mahasiswa m 
INNER JOIN  asisten a   ON m.NIM = a.nim
INNER JOIN  honor h     ON a.kd_ass = h.kd_ass
group by a.kd_ass,m.nama,h.honors
having h.honors > avg(h.honors)
```

Comment: This code really needs an explanation to the OP